# SharedPreferences после перезапуска удаляет элементы

Tags: java, android

У меня будильники. Создаю новый будильник, сохраняю время в Set в SharedPreferences.

```
buttons.add(dateFromTimePicker);

    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putStringSet(SAVE_DATE_CLOCK, buttons);
    ed.commit();
    //перезагружаю активити
    Intent i = new Intent( this, this.getClass() );
    finish();
    this.startActivity(i);
```

Затем **перезапускаю активити**. Получается, активити открывается и восстанавливает Set из  SharedPreferences, допустим,  3 будильника. Set хранит 3 даты. **Все ок.**

```
//перед открытием заполним активити кнопками
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    buttons = sPref.getStringSet(SAVE_DATE_CLOCK, new HashSet<String>());
 // Вот если я процесс работы не убил, а из работающего апк перезагружаю,
 //то buttons.size будет = 3 или 4 и тд, а если убью процесс.
 //Открываю апк и buttons.size = 1
```

**Убиваю процесс** работы приложения, опять открываю приложение и оп, размер set который я **восстанавливаю почему то не 3, а 1.** Один будильник.

Почему если я убиваю процесс работы приложения, допустим перезагружаю устройство, то кол-во элементов в set уменьшается до 1?

Comment: код покажи программы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего происходит перезапись в SP -сах .Проблема в. onCreate  или onStop onDestroy.
SharedPreferences.Editor использует шаблон Builder для создания транзакции фиксации. editor.putString (K, V) .putLong (к2, п) .commit (); После commit () вы должны использовать новый редактор или вызвать editor.clear () перед повторным использованием